# Typing properties in an object based on properties of another object (in Typescript)

Tags: typescript

I don't really know if what I want is even possible. I have tried for some time but now I am giving up and asking help from the community.

I would like to have a configuration object like this:

```
const someConfig: ParameterDescriptions = {
  someNumProperty: {
    name: 'numPropert',
    type: 'number',
    defaultValue: 42,
  },
  someStrProperty: {
    name: 'strPropert',
    type: 'string',
    defaultValue: 'some default value',
  },
  someBoolProperty: {
    name: 'boolProperty',
    type: 'boolean',
    defaultValue: false,
  },
};
```

And then an object like this:

```
interface MyState {
  someNumProperty: number;
  someStrProperty: string;
  someBoolProperty: boolean;
}
```

I would like to enforce that `MyState` has the same properties as `someConfig`, but with the type mentioned in each `ParameterDesc`'s type property

The `ParameterDescriptions` looks like this:

```
export interface BaseParameterDesc {
  name: string;
}

export interface NumberParameterDesc extends BaseParameterDesc {
  type: 'number';
  defaultValue?: number;
}

export interface StringParameterDesc extends BaseParameterDesc {
  type: 'string';
  defaultValue?: string;
}

export interface BooleanParameterDesc extends BaseParameterDesc {
  type: 'boolean';
  defaultValue?: boolean;
}

export type ParameterDesc =
    NumberParameterDesc|StringParameterDesc|BooleanParameterDesc;

export type ParameterDescriptions = {
  [key: string]: ParameterDesc;
};
```

But I don't know how to make the relationship between `MyState` and the instance of `ParameterDescription`.

One idea I had was to have the MyState implement some State type that tries to enforce this, but it doesn't really work

```
type State<PDesc extends ParameterDescriptions> = {
  // The .type at the end does not work, but I don't know
  // of alternatives
  [property in keyof PDesc]: PDesc[property].type;
};
```

Any ideas? Or this is just impossible?

All the code from this post can be found in this [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20BaseParameterDesc%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20NumberParameterDesc%20extends%20BaseParameterDesc%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20'number'%3B%0D%0A%20%20defaultValue%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20StringParameterDesc%20extends%20BaseParameterDesc%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20'string'%3B%0D%0A%20%20defaultValue%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20BooleanParameterDesc%20extends%20BaseParameterDesc%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20'boolean'%3B%0D%0A%20%20defaultValue%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20ParameterDesc%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20NumberParameterDesc%7CStringParameterDesc%7CBooleanParameterDesc%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20ParameterDescriptions%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20ParameterDesc%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Here%20is%20how%20I%20would%20like%20to%20use%20it%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20someConfig%3A%20ParameterDescriptions%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20someNumProperty%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'numPropert'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'number'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20defaultValue%3A%2042%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20someStrProperty%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'strPropert'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'string'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20defaultValue%3A%20'some%20default%20value'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20someBoolProperty%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'boolProperty'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'boolean'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20defaultValue%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20I%20would%20like%20to%20enforce%20that%20MyState%20has%20the%20same%20properties%20as%20someConfig%2C%0D%0A%2F%2F%20but%20with%20the%20type%20mentioned%20in%20each%20ParameterDesc's%20type%20property%0D%0Ainterface%20MyState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20someNumProperty%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20someStrProperty%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20someBoolProperty%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20One%20idea%20would%20be%20to%20have%20the%20MyState%20implement%20some%20State%20type%20that%20tries%20to%0D%0A%2F%2F%20enforce%20this%2C%20but%20it%20doesn't%20really%20work%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20State%3CPDesc%20extends%20ParameterDescriptions%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20The%20.type%20at%20the%20end%20does%20not%20work%2C%20but%20I%20don't%20know%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20of%20alternatives%0D%0A%20%20%5Bproperty%20in%20keyof%20PDesc%5D%3A%20PDesc%5Bproperty%5D.type%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem we need to solve is that the way you define `someConfig` is will not actually preserve the property names, it will end up being a variable that is indexable by any string. We can easily enforce the constraint of `ParameterDescriptions` and preserve actual key makes if we use a generic helper function:

```
function createConfig<T extends ParameterDescriptions>(c: T): T {
    return c;
}

const someConfig = createConfig({
    someNumProperty: {
        name: 'numPropert',
        type: 'number',
        defaultValue: 42,
    },
    someStrProperty: {
        name: 'strPropert',
        type: 'string',
        defaultValue: 'some default value',
    },
    someBoolProperty: {
        name: 'boolProperty',
        type: 'boolean',
        defaultValue: false,
    },
});
```

Now that `someConfig` preserves key names we can use a similar approach to yours, be just can't use the `type` property directly as a type, we need an extra type to map between type names and types (we could also use conditional types but this seems simpler in this case)

```
type TypeNamesToTypes = {
    boolean: boolean;
    string: string;
    number: number;
}
type State<T extends ParameterDescriptions> = { [P in keyof T]: TypeNamesToTypes[T[P]['type']]}
type MyState = State<typeof someConfig> // same as = {someNumProperty: number;someStrProperty: string;someBoolProperty: boolean;}
```

Playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20BaseParameterDesc%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20NumberParameterDesc%20extends%20BaseParameterDesc%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'number'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20defaultValue%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20StringParameterDesc%20extends%20BaseParameterDesc%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'string'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20defaultValue%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20BooleanParameterDesc%20extends%20BaseParameterDesc%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'boolean'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20defaultValue%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20ParameterDesc%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20NumberParameterDesc%20%7C%20StringParameterDesc%20%7C%20BooleanParameterDesc%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20ParameterDescriptions%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20ParameterDesc%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createConfig%3CT%20extends%20ParameterDescriptions%3E(c%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20c%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20someConfig%20%3D%20createConfig(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20someNumProperty%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'numPropert'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'number'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20defaultValue%3A%2042%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20someStrProperty%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'strPropert'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'string'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20defaultValue%3A%20'some%20default%20value'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20someBoolProperty%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'boolProperty'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'boolean'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20defaultValue%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TypeNamesToTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20boolean%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20string%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20number%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Atype%20State%3CT%20extends%20ParameterDescriptions%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20TypeNamesToTypes%5BT%5BP%5D%5B'type'%5D%5D%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20MyState%20%3D%20State%3Ctypeof%20someConfig%3E%20%2F%2F%20same%20as%20%3D%20%7BsomeNumProperty%3A%20number%3BsomeStrProperty%3A%20string%3BsomeBoolProperty%3A%20boolean%3B%7D)

Comment: Wow, this blew my mind! I think it will work for my needs. Thanks!